# How to break lines of HTML based on screen size

Tags: html, screen-size

I have a PhoneGap app that displays an unordered list utilizing jQuery mobile's layout. When you view the app on a smaller screen, the text overlaps and you can't read it anymore. I can't figure out how to have the line "break" so that it appears as two lines when the screen size is reduced, and one line when it is not reduced.

**Full screen**
[image: Full screen]

**Reduced screen**
[image: Reduced screen]

On the second line the text disappears, and is "hidden" by the numerical values. The code of that chunk looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a">
            <li data-role="list-divider"></li>

            <li><b>Revenues</b></li>
            <li>Gross Sales<span class="right">$543,600</span></li>
            <li>Less Sales Returned and Allowances<span class="right">$9,200</span></li>
            <li>Less Sales Discounts<span class="right">$5,100</span></li>
```

(continues on)

CSS:

```
span.right {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML+CSS.

Comment: The code posted does *not* produce the rendering in the images. You have settings that cause truncation indicated with an ellipsis.

Comment: I used JQuery mobiles' CSS and Javascript to produce the images, what you see is a product of their general formatting.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the `<wbr>` tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you can use

```
white-space: normal !important;
```

I was using `white-space: normal;` without the !important tag it does not become "wrap text" with JQuery mobile.

Answer (score 7):

Add a class to <br>.

Example:

Say u want to break <br> only at a custom screen size 358px n below.

HTML:

```
<br class="hidden-ss">
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 359px) {
  .hidden-ss {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

In reality u may have multiple @media screen breaking points already defined, e.g when using default Bootstrap:

HTML:

```
<br class="visible-ss hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
```

Define CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 358px) {        
  .visible-ss {
    display: block !important;
  }
```

Already pre-defined in Bootstrap:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .hidden-sm {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .hidden-md {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .hidden-lg {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: what can you do to replace <br> with a space?

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for a [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table):

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Table demo</title>
<style>
td:nth-child(2) { text-align: right }
</style>
<table><caption>Revenues</caption>
  <tr><td>Gross Sales <td>$543,600
  <tr><td>Less Sales Returned and Allowances <td>$9,200
  <tr><td>Less Sales Discounts <td>$5,100
</table>
```

If you really want the figures placed on the very right, you can add the CSS rule `table { width: 100% }`, but the presentation is much more readable without it.

Comment: This is what works in terms of functionality, but is there no way to do it with the lists? (The formatting changes)

Answer (score 0):

For smaller screens please use the CSS below so the span automatically comes in with the next line:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  span.right {
  display:block;
  text-align:right;
  clear:both;
 } 
}
```

Comment: This only brought the <span> item down a line, the "Less sales returned" line still is hidden on smaller screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap, you can put a breaking point depending on the screen size.

For example, to break line only on screens smaller than medium, you could put that in your html:

```
<br class="d-md-none">
```

More info on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/display/#hiding-elements